# Where can I put my data using Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I coded an Ember.js App. I displayed a Multiple Line Chart using d3.js.

In my Template 'index.hbs', we have a component 'multiple-line.hbs' that all code was writing in 'multiple-line.js' for building the chart.

The question is how can I put the data "donnees" to another place than 'multiple-line.js'?
Where can I put my data using 'model', 'route' and 'adapter'?

Here is my [code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/toyijelisu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file `donnees.js` and put it anywhere you want, for example in /app/data/donnees.js which looks like this:

```
export default {
"Cbio": [
{
"xValue": 1,
"yValue": 21
},
{
"xValue": 20,
"yValue": 150
},
{
"xValue": 40,
"yValue": 200
},...]};
```

And then, where you need the donnees:

```
import donnees from '<appname>/data/donnees';

var data  = d3.entries(donnees);
```